# Read from database and fill DataTable

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, datatable

I'm getting a set of data by a `DataReader` and assigning to a string. Now I need to fill the `DataTable` columns with the query fields. The `DataTable` is connected to a grid to display the filled data.

query is :

```
strSQL = "SELECT EmpCode,EmpID,EmpName FROM dbo.Employee
```

`DataTable` columns are `EmpCode, EmpID, EmpName`.

I need to read the query and assign to the columns of `DataTable` and fill the table. I have tried as below but i dont get the proper output,

```
Me.DtShifts.Tables("NonAllocated").Clear()
Me.DtShifts.Tables("NonAllocated").Load(dr)
```

Comment: Can you just read the data as a datatable in the first place and remove the DR?

Comment: I have 110 records and all data are filled as zeros in the table in 110 rows..

Comment: Have you checked the value in your dr? and how do you populate your dr from a datareader?

Comment: Try
            strSQL = "SELECT EmpCode,EmpID,EmpName FROM dbo.Employee"
            dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(strCNString, CommandType.Text, strSQL)

            'Me.DtShifts.NonAllocated.Rows.Add(dr.Item("EmpCode"), dr.Item("EmpID"), dr.Item("EmpName"))

           
            Me.DtShifts.Tables("NonAllocated").Clear()
            Me.DtShifts.Tables("NonAllocated").Load(dr)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Connection object is for illustration only. The DataAdapter is the key bit:

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT EmpCode,EmpID,EmpName FROM dbo.Employee"
Dim dtb As New DataTable
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
  cnn.Open()
  Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
    dad.Fill(dtb)
  End Using
  cnn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Just want to ask, when I try to copy this code into VB.Net 2003, I get an error saying that `using` is not declared. If this is the accepted answer, then why doesn't it work on my end? Do I need to add something else?

Comment: That's a very old version of VB.NET, perhaps it predates the introduction of the `Using` keyword

Comment: I see. Well at least the code still works if I remove all instances of `Using`. So it's all good.

Comment: Change `Using cnn...` to `Dim cnn...` and change `End Using` to `cnn.Dispose()`

Comment: You can download the latest Community (free) version of Visual Basic here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Function LoaderData(ByVal strSql As String) As DataTable
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim dad As SqlDataAdapter

    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    cnn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.mySqlConnectionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        dad = New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
        cnn.Close()
        dad.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        cnn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return dtb
End Function
```

Comment: If you put your connection and adapters in a Using-Block (always recommended), it will automatically dispose of it for you.  The DataAdapter can open and close the connection for you, so that code is unnecessary.  Unclear how this improves on the accepted answer from 6 years ago.