# Is there a way to add a dataset to a report without binding it to an actual dataset?

Tags: vb.net, report

I am trying to design a bill generating tool with VB.NET in Visual Studio 2015. I am building my bill elements using a report. I know the usual practice is to assign a dataset to a report as datasource and use a table adapter to fill that dataset. I was wondering if there is a way to manually fill the dataset and assign it to a report as datasource?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually fill the dataset and assign it to a report" ?

Answer (score 0):

You do need a dataset or other datasource at designtime (ok you can edit the rdlc file by hand if you insist, but it's not for the faint of heart) but you don't need to use the same dataset at runtime that you used as a design aid. It just has to match in terms of the properties it exposes. [This blog entry should help.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/magreer/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread:

[Read from database and fill DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844358/read-from-database-and-fill-datatable)

The example fills a DataTable which can then be assigned to your report as a data source. A DataSet is simply a collection of data tables.