# Displaying the SUM in asp.net label of rows data in SQL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is my code, and i want to display the SUM of the data in a label after clicking the submit button in my previous page.

any answer will highly appreciated.

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

 Session("EMPID") = Request("EMPID")

//Query for getting the sum
sc1.CommandText = "select SUM (Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20) as TotalScore from  tblModule1 where EmpID = ' " & Session("EmpID") & " '"
da1.Fill(ds1)

//Condition
If ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then

                lblResult.Text = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TotalScore").ToString


            End If

            ds1.Clear()
            ds1.Tables.Clear()

        End If
```

Comment: What is your issue or your questions?  Did you try running it?  what was the results?

Comment: my issue is that, i cannot display the data from sql in the lblResult.text.

Comment: Did you step through the code in debug mode and confirm that you are getting a value reutnred from your DB to be put in the label?  Maybe no value is getting reutrned?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors prompt, but when i try to run the query in the sql i got the value which is "11". and i want that value to display in lblresult.text

Comment: See this, your missing a lot of steps for actually executing the SQL 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844358/read-from-database-and-fill-datatable

Comment: Then you just need to do what Brad is telling in the third comment. If you checked the query runs OK in SQL Server, you need to check if the same value arrives to your app, for ex, doing a debug run, and checking step by step if the process go into the IF or not, and if it does, check the value for: ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TotalScore").ToString. (I never use this syntax, I always use this one: ds1.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TotalScore").ToString, but in any case, is important to take control of your code and check what value is returning in a certain moment, debugging your application)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us how you declare ds1, sc1 and da1, and how you do a relation with them...
Probably between sc1.commandtext = ... and da1.Fill... lines, you need to add something like da1.SelectCommand = sc1

```
sc1.CommandText = "select SUM (Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20) as TotalScore from  tblModule1 where EmpID = ' " & Session("EmpID") & " '"
da1.SelectCommand = sc1
da1.Fill(ds1)
```

Obviously the Select command needs to have a connection object correctly set.

Probably if you show us all the related code we can help you better.