# Read from database into dictionary VB.net

Tags: vb.net, db2, odbc

I have a problem that is solved by selecting all columns of particular records from a DB2 database and shows them to the user as a datagridview.
The user will select a single record changes a column's value and saves. Doing so will insert an updated record, so to do that I need the columns names since some may be empty and *I have to recreate the record.*

The only way I came up with is creating a dictionary that contains the **column name** and **whatever value it corresponds to**, manipulating it somehow and doing an insert.

For instance if I do not need the column name, I do it using *LotsList* as a List(Of LotDTO).

```
Using db2reader As OdbcDataReader = db2Com.ExecuteReader
      While db2reader.Read
            LotsList.Add(New LOTDTO With
                             {
                             .LotNo = If(IsDBNull(db2reader("dlot")), "", db2reader("dlot")),
                             .ExpDate = If(IsDBNull(db2reader("ExpDate")), "", db2reader("ExpDate")),

                              }
                         )
       End While
```

But how to do it if I am to use a Dictionary(Of String, LotDTO).
Here is my query.

`Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ITEMID, TRXDATE, TRXTYPE, REFERNO, ... From DB Where ....`

Also open to any suggestion that is not beyond the capabilities of a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead I would recommend you use a `DataTable` object, which is designed for this sort of thing.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845783/741136) for how to use a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable (you will need to convert the code to use ODBC classes).

Then you can use the `DataGridView.DataSource` property to bind the DataTable.

Then use the following code to retrieve the edited values from the DataGridView for your update statements (dgvSource is the name of the DataGridView):

```
Dim dgvr As DataGridViewRow = dgvSource.Rows(intRow)
Dim drw As DataRow = DirectCast(dgvr.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
```

(don't just use `.Rows` as this will give you the wrong data if the user sorts the datagridview)