DataGridView returns "Operation cannot be performed in this event handler" on .Rows.Clear() in VB.net
I've been writing a database application to go with a personal project, and given my self-taught coding experience I'm surprised I've gotten as far as I have. Decades ago, I coded dBase/Clipper, then did fairly well with VB6 at a borderline moderate level, and ceased coding altogether till now. I came back to it out of need, finding myself working with VB.net (2022), which I needn't say is very different from VB6, and SQLite. I've picked up VB.net fairly well and have been able to resolve most of my coding problems unaided. But now I have one issue that has me stumped:
The form loads data from two columns in one (source) table into a DataGridView (DGV). Selecting a row checks the record and nominally allows for adding information pertinent to it into a different table. The source table also has a column (Boolean) which, if set TRUE raises a prompt to the user. If the response is YES, the record can be processed as if it were FALSE. This route sets a flag on the source record so it is excluded from the DGV on the next iteration. However, when the response is NO, the record gets the exclusion set, and then the form resets. To accomplish the reset, I clear the entire DGV with .Rows.Clear() and then reload it from scratch.
When there is no prompt, or when there is and the response is YES, the DGV clears and reloads as expected. However, if there is a prompt and the response is NO, I get an "Operation cannot be performed in this event handler" error. Code fragments follow:
Code to handle the reset scenario described above:
    Private Sub DataGrid_SelectRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvRecords.RowEnter

        ' *** Code to set up a few things for normal processing ***

        If strDGVCell01 <> "" Then
            If FLBG_TableColumnLookup(appDataSource, tableArchive, strFilterString, "[BlankFrame]") = True Then
                If FLBG_CustomMsgBox(strDGVCell01 & " " & noticeBlankFrame, __ModuleLongName, "QYN") = vbNo Then
                    FLBG_TableRecordUpdate(appDataSource, tableArchive, "[InLibrary]=True", strFilterString)
                    RecycleForm()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If

        LookupArchiveRecordDetails()
        LookupMediaRecordDetails()
        txtYear.Select()
    End Sub

Code to recycle the form:
   Private Sub RecycleForm()
       ResetVariables()
       UpdateImageViewport(False, pctImgPreview, strSourceFileFQN, btnViewImage, lblResolutionPX, lblFileSize)
       FLBG_PopulateDataGridFromDB(dgvRecords, appDataSource, tableArchive, strDGVColumns, "[InLibrary]=False", strDGVSortFilter)
       dgvRecords.CurrentCell = Nothing
       grpLibrary.Select()
   End Sub

...and the code that resets the variables (including the DGV):
    Private Sub ResetVariables()
        blnImageInLibrary = False
        blnGotArchiveNotes = False
        chkAltSrc.Checked = False
        cmbAltSrc.SelectedIndex = -1
        rdoModReg.Checked = True
        strFileBase = ""
        strFileMods = ""
        strFileSNum = ""
        strFileType = ""
        strFileVary = ""
        strPathYear = ""
        strSourceFileFQN = ""
        lblFQN.Text = ""
        lblNumber.Text = "______"
        txtNote.Clear()
        txtYear.Clear()
        txtVariant.Clear()
        dgvRecords.Rows.Clear()         ' *** Error happens here ***
        intCountNew = Nothing
        intCountOld = Nothing
        strConditionString = ""
        strFilterString = ""
        strLookupValue = ""
    End Sub

Finally, the code that handles a normal record update ("Save" button):
    Private Sub Button_AddUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        ' *** Code to set up a few things for normal processing ***

        strConditionString = strValue05 & "," & strValue06 & "," & strValue04 & "," &
                             strValue03 & "," & rdoModC2M.Checked & "," &
                             rdoModM2C.Checked & "," & strValue07 & "," &
                             strValue08 & "," & strValue09
        FLBG_TableRecordInsert(appDataSource, tableLibrary, strColumnFilter, strConditionString)
        FLBG_TableRecordUpdate(appDataSource, tableYearTally, "[LastCount]=" & intCountNew, "[Year]=" & strValue01)
        FLBG_TableRecordUpdate(appDataSource, tableArchive, "[InLibrary]=" & blnImageInLibrary, strFilterString)

        RecycleForm()
    End Sub

Bottom line? I'm not sure what I'm missing here. The only difference is that the one that works is initiated from a Button Object event, while the other is initiated off a dialog Y/N prompt. If that ends up being the reason, then I don't know how to trigger it without adding a button object click right after the Y/N...
I did some digging about this error, and the closest I get is this older SO article, "Operation cannot be performed in this event handler", and others like it on other sites. However, in all those instances, the developers asking the question are trying to remove just one row from the content of the DGV. In contrast, I'm zapping the whole thing. Nevertheless, I've tried all of the solutions posited to no avail, except those referring to changing the table binding as that doesn't apply (the table isn't bound).
If it helps any, here are the error details:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Clear()
   at ILiAD.ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.ResetVariables() in F:\Development\Application\Code\Basic\VB 2022\ILiAD\ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.vb:line 667
   at ILiAD.ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.RecycleForm() in F:\Development\Application\Code\Basic\VB 2022\ILiAD\ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.vb:line 635
   at ILiAD.ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.yadda() in F:\Development\Application\Code\Basic\VB 2022\ILiAD\ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.vb:line 368
   at ILiAD.ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.DataGrid_SelectRow(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) in F:\Development\Application\Code\Basic\VB 2022\ILiAD\ILiAD_ManageImageLibrary.vb:line 355
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at ILiAD.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83


I would recommend you use a DataTable to store your data, and then bind it to the DGV using the .DataSource property. I find DGVs behave more predictably when I do this.

Did you try dgvRecords.DataSource = Nothing?

@SSS and @HardCode: The DGV is not bound to a DataTable. Aside from my using SQLite for this, my command of VB.net is not proficient enough. I can tell you that I'm using System.Data.SQLite as the database provider, if that helps any.
Yes, I did try dgvRecords.DataSource = Nothing, but no joy.
In case it makes a difference, there are two calls into the routine which executes dgvRecords.Rows.Clear(). The first is the one I described in the original post, and which initiates from within the DGV select handler. The second initiates in the "Add" ButtonClick event; it works properly!

@GrafEberstein you will find it much easier to bind the dgv. Here is how to fill a datatable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844358/read-from-database-and-fill-datatable/10845783#10845783 then set dgvRecords.DataSource = dtb
